# IE9 decline response of http server

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9

IE9 decline response of below ajax request to local http server.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',    
        url: "127.0.0.1",
        data:{res:"pending"},
        dataType: "text",
        crossDomain: false, 
        cache: false,
        success: success,
        error: error
});
```

respone of server :

```
    "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
    "Access-control-allow-methods: *\r\n"
    "Access-control-allow-origin: *\r\n"
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
    "Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n"
```

Is there any reason???? what IE9 expects??

Comment: IE9 expects the variable `success` to have actually something in it....response from your server-side script **maybe**?

Comment: thx bodi0... its works in IE9 , but not in IE8, any more suggestions for it??

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look at the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `contentType` parameter and  `dataType` as well. Note that possible values are `xml, json, jsonp, text, script, html`. The default is Intelligent Guess by jQuery.

As stated in documentation:

`dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.`

`contentType: When sending data to the server, use this content-type.`

You should specify that you are sending HTML type data (by using `html` as `dataType`, because your server returns HTML in the response header (`Content-Type: text/html`), also if you have script tags in returned result - those will be **evaluated** when inserted in the DOM.

Comment: In case of IE8, server gets request and send response successfully as above and exceed `success ` field, thought IE8 decline response, where IE9 accepts.